# How can I recursively find the *directories* containing a file of a certain type?

Tags: python, glob

I have a set of .bam, files scattered inside a tree of folders.  Not every directory contains such a file.  I know how to recursively get the path of the files themselves using glob, but not the directory containing them.

```
import glob2
bam_files = glob2.glob('/data2/**/*.bam')
print bam_files
```

The above code gives the .bam files, but I want just the folders.  Wondering if there is a direct way to do this using glob without regular expressions.

Comment: You could just loop over your search results and use os.path.dirname() to get the parent directories.

Comment: thanks!  that worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a set and `os.path.dirname()` [https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname]:

```
import glob2
import os 
bam_dirs = {os.path.dirname(p) for p in glob2.glob('/data2/**/*.bam')}
print bam_dirs
```